# Has the doctor ever regenerated as a woman? Could he?

Tags: doctor-who

If I recall my very fuzzy history of Dr. Who, the Doctor always regenerates as a man, of roughly the same approximate age and height, and roughly the same nationality and 'race'.

Ignoring for now the possibility of a Doctor with a different skin tone or accent, has there ever been a regeneration in side-canon where the Doctor became a woman?

More to the point, is it even *possible* for this to happen?

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, but not in anything resembling canon**

It happened during the *[The Curse of Fatal Death](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Curse_of_Fatal_Death_%28TV_story%29)*, which was a Comic Relief parody of Doctor Who.  Joanna Lumley, of *Ab Fab* fame, played The Doctor.

In the normal show, however, [it remains a possibility](https://www.blastr.com/2013-9-30/why-moffat-reasonably-confident-well-have-female-doctor-someday), at least according to Moffat:

> "One day I'm reasonably confident somebody in this [showrunner] role - whether it's me or someone else - will say not, 'Let's cast a woman', they'll say, 'That person, that's the one who could the be the Doctor'. You're just casting someone that you think will set that role on fire. I think for now that is Peter - I thought it was Matt [Smith] before - it's not about the gender thing."

In-universe, The Doctor refers to [The Corsair](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Corsair) as specifically swapping genders.  He's mentioned in the regular series during [The Doctor's Wife](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/32-4.htm):

> DOCTOR: The mark of the Corsair. Fantastic bloke. He had that snake as a tattoo in every regeneration. Didn't feel like himself unless he had the tattoo. Or herself, a couple of times. Ooo, she was a bad girl.

**So in-universe it can happen, out-of-universe it has been alluded that it might happen specifically for The Doctor**

Comment: And tbh, even if there was an in-universe "reason" - they would write around it if they wanted to cast a woman.  Just like the regen limit.

Comment: The Corsair, mentioned in The Doctor's Wife (and probably other places not off the top of my head), has changed genders.

Comment: Also, in the episode "The Doctor's Wife" the Eleventh Doctor said the following about another Time Lord called "The Corsair": "He had that snake as a tattoo in every regeneration. Didn't feel like himself without the tattoo. Or herself, a couple of times. Ooh, she was a bad girl!" So unless the Doctor was lying, this shows it's a possibility for Time Lords to change gender when they regenerate.

Comment: Ah thanks, added - I thought there was a specific example, and good on Gaiman for bringing it into the show where canon isn't a big issue.

Comment: Doctor himself thought he was a girl when he regenerated into his 11th (13th?) incarnation and saw the new hair.  Although I'm sure it was intended to highlight Matt's feminine hairstyle at the time :)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=sVEY5AL5zzk#t=65

Comment: eluded -> alluded. They're homonyms with very different meanings, but the edit is less than 6 characters. =)

Comment: Good catch, thanks :)

Comment: In "Hell Bent", the Doctor shoots the General who switches gender in his/her regeneration. Given that it happened to that timelord, no reason it couldn't also happen to the Doctor.